# Mac Terminal and applications version installed

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

I have the zsh in Ventura OS. I know that I have already installed the following apps:

- Books.app (which came already in the system)
- Brackets
- MAMP (Package for MySQL, Apache and PHP)
- Adobe Photoshop

I want to see the output, the version running, through commands in the terminal. The spotlight is set to look for all directories, including Applications. How do I know if an application is installed and which version is it?

I typed the following and you can see the outcome. To look for a particular application you need to type all the path, right? I dragged them from the finder directory (I learned that in a video).

```
macsito@Macsitos-iMac-Pro ~ % /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app -v
zsh: permission denied: /Applications/MAMP/MAMP.app

macsito@Macsitos-iMac-Pro ~ % /System/Applications/Books.app -v
zsh: permission denied: /System/Applications/Books.app

macsito@Macsitos-iMac-Pro ~ % /Applications/Brackets.app -v
zsh: permission denied: /Applications/Brackets.app

macsito@Macsitos-iMac-Pro ~ % /Applications/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2023/Adobe\ Photoshop\ 2023.app -v
```

Comment: If you do a `ls -ld` on the applications, you will see that they are directories.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.app` is just a folder and it doesn't respond to any parameters in Terminal. If you want to get the app version you have to check it in its `Info.plist` file. You can do it in Terminal using:

```
defaults read /path/to/Application.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString
```

So for Books.app it'll be

```
defaults read /System/Applications/Books.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString
```

which gives me `6.0`

Comment: Just being curious: Is it mandatory, or just highly likely, that the plist contains a _CFBundleShortVersionString_  entry?

Comment: @user1934428 I can't find the info about that being mandatory key. But I haven't seen an app without it. More info aobut the key can be found here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-111349